# Statistical Power and Type II Error

Tags: probability, inference

Let the power function be defined as $\beta(\theta)=P_{\theta}(\mathbf{X} \in R)$, where $R$ is the rejection region associated to the test being considered.

Can I state that the Probability of type II error is equal to $\displaystyle 1-\int_{\theta \in \Theta_1} \beta(\theta) \ d\theta$?

Below we see a definition of statistical Power, in Casella and Berger 'Statistical Inference'. 
[image]

I don't seem to be able to understand how defining in this is consistent with the definition of power that I find on Wiki,i.e. Power is the probability of rejecting the null when the alternative is true, unless the answer to my question is 'yes'...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting idea, but no. For example: the integral is *not* a probability in most cases: we could think of many examples where it is larger than 1.

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst But isn't the beta function a conditional (on theta) probability? Could you give an example where the integral is greater than 1? Thanks ;)

Comment: That is exactly the problem: $\beta(\theta)$ is a conditional probability and not a joint probability. From a Bayesian perspective, it would make sense to say $\text{Prob}[X\in R] = \int_{\theta} \text{Prob}[X\in R, \Theta \in (\theta,\theta+d\theta)] $, but $\int_{\theta} \text{Prob}[X\in R | \Theta = \theta] d\theta$ can not reasonably be interpreted as a probability. I'm not saying it is not a useful quantity, but I don't think it is a probability.

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst I've edited the question to make it more clear my reasoning. Thanks

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst you're right. but then how can the wiki definition be consistent with the definition in the book?

Comment: I think the difference between the wiki and the book is in the notation. "$\beta$" in the book is power, or 1-(Type II error probability). "$\beta$" in the wiki is Type II error probability, or 1-power. The latter is the more commonly accepted notation.

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst Just one more question: Do we compute the power for a range of values of $\theta$ or for just one value at a time?

Comment: I think we should go back to the idea of hypothesis testing:  the parameters $\theta$ has one true value that is unkown.  We have some ''idea'' about the value and we want to test whether this ''idea'' about the value is confirmed or rejected by the data.  But the important thing that there is only one true value for $\theta$.  All other values are impossible (so probability is zero) , only the one true (but unknown) value is possible.  So as @StijnDeVuyst says, there is only one value for $\theta$. Since you don't know that value, one tries to compute the power for different values (cont.)

Comment: ... (cont). for $\theta$ but that is only because we do some kind of ''robustness'' check, we do not know the true value, so we can not compute the true power and therefore we compute it for several values for $\theta$ and analyse the ''power function''.  But know that only one true value exists. So only one value of this function is the 'real' one.

Comment: When you compute power you do it at some particular value for the parameter that's different from the null value. You get different values of power for different values of the parameter, yielding a *power curve* or if you're varying both dimensions in a two dimensional parameter, a power surface (etc). Numerous posts on site display power curves. One example is [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85878/interpretation-of-power-and-detectable-difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we should go back to the idea of hypothesis testing: the parameter $\theta$ has one true value that is unkown. We have some ''idea'' about the value and we want to test whether this ''idea'' about the value is confirmed or rejected by the data.

But the important thing that there is only one true value for $\theta$. All other values are impossible (so probability is zero) , only the one true (but unknown) value is possible. So as @StijnDeVuyst says, there is only one value for $\theta$.

Since you don't know that value, one tries to compute the power for different values for $\theta$ but that is only because we do some kind of ''robustness'' check, we do not know the true value, so we can not compute the true power and therefore we compute it for several values for $\theta$ and analyse the ''power function''.

But know that only one true value exists. So only one value of this function is the 'real' one.