# Confused about when to use z-test and p-value test for hypothesis testing

Tags: t-test, p-value, z-test

Can anyone help me solve this confusion? I don’t know why z-test and p-value test for hypothesis testing is used for this, given that the pattern between the two questions are same.

1. Records show that students on average score less than or equal to 850 on a test. A test prep company says that students who take their course will score an average higher than this. To test, they sampled 1000 students who scored an average of 856 with standard deviation of 98 after taking the course. At 0.05 test the company’s claim.

z-test is used for this.

2. A newspaper reports that the average age a woman gets married is 25 years or younger. A researcher thinks that average age is older. He samples 213 women and gets an average age of 25.4 years with standard deviation of 2.3 years. With 95% confidence, test researcher’s claim.

p-value test is used for this.

Comment: What is "p-value test"? Z-test and many other tests also return p-values. From the description, it is not clear why z-test would be the correct answer, it seems like it rather [should be the t-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85804/choosing-between-z-test-and-t-test).