# False Discovery Rate pvalue correction method

Tags: false-discovery-rate

I am trying different methods to correct a p-value from simulated data,namely the following "holm", "hochberg", "hommel", "bonferroni","BH", "BY" in the p.adjust command of R and then consrtuct the following confusion matrix [image]

The problem is that in the first four methods i get V=0,only "BH" and "BY" methods give V>0.Is this expected?

Comment: They are different methods; why would you expect them to always give the same results?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FPR (false positive rate) vs FDR (false discovery rate)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/336455/fpr-false-positive-rate-vs-fdr-false-discovery-rate) Your first 4 methods control for the probability of making _any_ false-positive finding; the "BH" and "BY" methods control for the proportion of positive findings expected to be false (false discovery rate).