# Does $\Pr(\text{Type I error})$ ever not equal $\alpha$ with continuous data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

This question: [Comparing and contrasting, p-values, significance levels and type I error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33453/comparing-and-contrasting-p-values-significance-levels-and-type-i-error#33500) cites exceptions that arise when using discrete data. Are there other exceptions with continuous data as well?

Comment: You mean *apart* from misspecification of functional forms, link functions, error distributions, heteroskadastic form and unobserved variables? No... if you have all these right, then mathematics guarantee your alpha levels. (Of course, there are people out there who keep claiming that the null hypothesis does not hold in any question you'd want to examine, anyway. Pay no attention to those people.)

Comment: In real, nonsimulated data, does the true P(Type I error) ever exactly equal $\alpha$? Assumptions don't hold (when do all the assumptions hold?), people choose hypotheses after they've seen the data, choose procedures after checking assumptions, omit outliers, etc etc.

Comment: The following is extremely common but so trivial I wonder whether it is what you have in mind: in one-tailed testing of a parameter, such as $H_0:\mu\le 0$ *versus* $H_A:\mu\gt 0$, when the true value of $\mu$ is strictly different from $0$ then the chance of a Type I error ("false positive") is usually strictly less than the nominal $\alpha$. Did you perhaps mean "Pr(Type I error)" to mean something different, such as the actual *size* of a test? Or, possibly, is your question directed at elucidating the distinction between test size and chance of Type I error?

Comment: My motivation was simpler; I'd read that Pr(Type I error) was meant to equal α if the null hypothesis held, and I was wondering what conditions needed to hold in order for that to be true. It seems the required conditions are so numerous and so unlikely to hold that it will almost never be true for non-simulated data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In real, nonsimulated data, does the true P(Type I error) ever actually equal to $\alpha$?

Assumptions don't hold (when do all the assumptions hold?), people choose hypotheses after they've seen the data, choose procedures after checking assumptions, omit outliers, etc etc.

Even 'exact' nonparametric procedures rely on assumptions that rarely hold exactly (such as independence or exchangeability).

Treat p-values as -- under perfect conditions -- sometimes reasonably accurate (and the rest of the time as possibly informative fictions) and you may not go too far wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The only example I can readily think of is [data dredging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging).  For example, the probability of a type I error is much higher than alpha if many tests are run (but this is not corrected for) and only those that are 'significant' are reported.  The obvious examples would be multiple comparisons via many $t$-tests without something like the Bonferroni correction, or stepwise variable selection.