# When doesn't the chi-squared statistic follow the chi-squared distribution?

Tags: chi-squared-test, chi-squared-distribution

When we do a chi-squared test (to test goodness of fit or the dependence of two variables), we *assume* that the the chi-squared statistic follows the chi-squared distribution.

- Shouldn't we first check if the chi-squared statistic follows the chi-squared distribution in that particular case?
- If yes, then how do we do that?
- Or have I got it all mixed up and my question itself is wrong?

Comment: Learn about the chi squared distribution. Hope this helps. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGvVZmZ1g5c

Comment: My post at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17148 answers these questions by detailing the assumptions that must be checked as well as illustrating what can go wrong when they don't hold.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually pretty straightforward.  The [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) is a distribution of continuous values.  A chi-squared test statistic may or may not be able to take any positive real value.  For example, the test statistic for a likelihood ratio test can take continuous values, but the test statistic from a chi-squared test of independence for a 2x2 contingency table can only take a finite set of discrete values.  The former may match the theoretical distribution just fine, but the latter will be an approximation.  If your sample is large enough, the approximation isn't a problem and the Yates' correction for continuity also helps a lot, so in practice it isn't usually something that you need to worry about often.  To understand this further, it may help to read my answer here: [Comparing and contrasting, p-values, significance levels and type I error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/33500/7290).

Comment: I gave this +1, but a small niggle worries at me -- the small-sample distribution of an LRT (even when continuous) may not be very near chi-square. I'd suggest "may match" rather than "will match" as more generally correct.