# sample frame representing the true population

Tags: anova, sampling, sample-size

(i) Is it true to say that if the sample frame is not a random selection (such as a convenience sample), then the sample frame is not representative of the true population?

(ii) We can always do a G*Power analysis to determine the sample size. But how do we determine if the sample frame represents the true population or not?

(iii) How is sample size important in order to avoid making Type I or Type II errors?

Thank you

Comment: I think that by "sample frame", you meant "sample". There is nothing random about a sampling frame. See,e.g.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_frame

Answer (score 2):

> (i) Is it true to say that if the sample frame is not a random
>   selection (such as a convenience sample), then the sample frame is not
>   representative of the true population?

In short, yes. Elaborating: "representative" doesn't really have a clear definition - Kruskall & Mosteller tracked 9(!) distinct meanings of it in a series of papers in 1980. I think the consensus in modern statistics is that "representative" means that every item was sampled with known probability. So a convenience sample is not representative *by definition.*

> (ii) We can always do a G*Power analysis to determine the sample size.
>   But how do we determine if the sample frame represents the true
>   population or not?

There are a number of ways to approach this problem. Bethlehem, Schouten & Cobben (in the [RISQ project](http://www.risq-project.eu/)) suggest one such indicator.

> (iii) How is sample size important in order to avoid making Type I or Type II errors?

I'll refer you to whuber's excellent reply in this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9653/can-a-small-sample-size-cause-type-1-error).